# What is the best approach to replace Parse.Collections in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

Parse.com has removed the `Backbone` style `Parse.Collection` from the JS SKD (from here https://parse.com/docs/downloads):

> SDK no longer contains Backbone-specific behavior. Moving forward, the core SDK will not be tied to any single framework, but we will work with the community to produce up-to-date bindings like Parse+React. The major changes are the removal of Parse.Collection, and allowing Parse.Objects to act as event channels.

I have a lot of code that uses parse.collection, both in web apps and node.js apps. What options do I have to replace this collections to something similar? or switch to another best practice?

for example, in the case of my web app, should I wrap the parse sdk in backbone to keep using this functionality?

thanks for your ideas

Comment: so far I've been using my own implementation (to the prototype) of Parse.Collection... but not as convenient as it should be. I found that Backbone.Collection won't work to contain Parse.Objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the Backbone parse function with :

```
parse: function (response) {
    return response.results;
},
```

Comment: It's not only about the parse method of Backbone.Collection. one would need to replace the `fetch` function as well.